# R formula construction issues

Tags: r, shiny

I have this Shiny App in which, at some point, I run a regression using npsf::sf function.

```
library(shiny)
library(npsf)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(42)

df <- data.frame(
  ID = rep(1:100, each = 2), 
  Time = rep(1:2, times = 100),
  output = sample(18:60, 200, replace = TRUE), 
  inputone = abs(rnorm(200, mean = 2000, sd = 500)),
  inputtwo = abs(rnorm(200, mean = 20, sd = 8)),
  inputthree = abs(rnorm(200, mean = 60, sd = 30)),
  inputfour = abs(rnorm(200, mean = 12, sd = 15))
)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Input Output"),

    # Sidebar 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            uiOutput("InpSel")
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           dataTableOutput("tabsum_sg")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$InpSel <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      selectizeInput("v.dependent", h5("Dependent variable"), 
                     choices = names(df),
                     selected =  "output" , multiple = FALSE),
      selectizeInput("v.predictor", h5("Predictor variables"), 
                     choices = names(df),
                     selected = names(df)[4:7],  multiple = TRUE),
      uiOutput("squaredP")
    )
  })
  
  
  output$squaredP <- renderUI({
    req(input$v.predictor)
    selectizeInput("v.sqpredictor", h5("Squared Predictor variables"), 
                   choices = c("Select" = "", input$v.predictor),
                   multiple = TRUE)
  })
  
  
  EstimationSfa <- reactive({
    req(input$v.dependent, input$v.predictor)
    
    model_data <<- df %>%
      mutate(trend = Time - min(Time, na.rm = TRUE) +1)
    
    dep <- input$v.dependent
    pred <- input$v.predictor
    sqpred <- input$v.sqpredictor
    
    
    form <- as.formula(paste(paste0("log( ", dep, " )"),
                             paste(paste("log( ", pred, " )", collapse = " + "), "+ trend"),
                             sep = " ~ "))
    
    model <- npsf::sf(formula = form,
                      data = model_data, it = c("ID", "Time"),
                      prod = TRUE, model = "4comp",
                      eff.time.invariant = FALSE, mean.u.0i.zero = TRUE, R = 500, lmtol = 1e-3, maxit = 500)
    
  })
  
  
  ResTe <- reactive({
    req(EstimationSfa())
    
      
      df_est <- df %>%
        rename(t = Time, id = ID) %>%
        left_join((EstimationSfa()$efficiencies_it), by = c("id", "t"))
      
      return(df_est)  # Don't forget to return the result

   })  
  
  
  output$tabsum_sg <- renderDataTable({
    req(ResTe())
    te.analysis <- ResTe()
    
      te.analysis <- te.analysis %>%
        select(Persistent = te_i, 
         Transient =  te_it,
         Overall = te_over)
      
    
    
    tmp <- do.call(data.frame, 
                   list(Mean = round(apply(te.analysis, 2, mean, na.rm = TRUE), 2),
                        SD = round(apply(te.analysis, 2, sd, na.rm = TRUE),2),
                        Median = round(apply(te.analysis, 2, median, na.rm = TRUE),2),
                        Min = round(apply(te.analysis, 2, min, na.rm = TRUE),2),
                        Max = round(apply(te.analysis, 2, max, na.rm = TRUE),2)
                   ))
    tmp <- data.frame("Variables" = row.names(tmp), tmp)
    datatable(tmp, rownames = FALSE, 
              extensions = c('Buttons'), 
              options = list(
                dom = 'Bfrtip',
                buttons = c('colvis', 'excel', 'pdf')))
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I will like to change the formula so that when the user chooses one or several variables to square
the variables are included in the formula.

Here is how the formula is right now:

```
"log( output ) ~ log(  inputone  ) + log(  inputtwo  ) + log(  inputthree  ) + log(  inputfour  ) + trend"
```

Here is an example of the desired formula when the user selects inputone and inputtwo under Squared Predictor variables:

```
"log( output ) ~ log(  inputone  ) + log(  inputtwo  ) + log(  inputthree  ) + log(  inputfour  ) + I(log(inputone)^2) +  I(log(inputtwo)^2) + trend"
```

I tried this

```
form <- as.formula(paste(paste0("log( ", dep, " )"),
                         paste(paste("log( ", pred, " )", collapse = " + "), paste("I(log(", sqpred, ")^2)", collapse = " + "), sep = " + "),
                         sep = " ~ "))
```

and this

```
# Create a list of predictors including squared terms
predictors <- c(pred, sapply(sqpred, function(sq) paste("I(", sq, ")^2"), USE.NAMES = FALSE))

# Create formula string
formula_str <- paste(paste0("log(", dep, ")"),
                     paste(paste("log(", predictors, ")", collapse = " + "), "+ trend"),
                     sep = " ~ ")

# Convert formula string to formula object
form <- as.formula(formula_str)
```

Thank you.
Kindly bear in mind that actual names of variables are like this `Trade (% of GDP) [NE.TRD.GNFS.ZS]`.

Comment: Hello @Esseda. So the whole question is about how to build a formula from variables having difficult names. Try to be more focused on the specific problem (here shiny seems not be the problem so no need to talk about it :-) It will be easier for us to answer your question

Comment: Hello @Billy34, thank you. Actually, Shiny is part of the problem. I want the formula to work within a shiny app. In a non interactive context or if I knew precisely the name of the selected variables, all I will have to do is write the formula like this "log( output ) ~ log(  inputone  ) + ... + I(log(inputone)^2) +  I(log(inputtwo)^2) + trend". Because of the interactive part I have to write the formula based on potential selection and I am having a hard time writing the code so it will include the squared terms either with simple names or difficult ones. Thank you.

Comment: I think the problem lies in how you format the formula, especially for ill named variables that should be enclosed in backquotes. Look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backquotes are there to handle "strange" variable names. sqpred should be NULL if nothing selected (according to multiple=TRUE)

```
# these variable are extracted from your inputs
# they are here just as sample values
dep <- "output"
pred <- c("inputone", "inputtwo", "inputthree", "inputfour")
sqpred <- c("inputone", "inputtwo")
trend <- "trend"

# format predictors
pred <- paste0("log( `",pred,"` )", collapse=" + ")

# format squared predictors if some selected
if(!is.null(sqpred)) {
  sqpred <- paste0("I(log( `",sqpred,"` )^2)", collapse=" + ")
}

# build formula from parts
# first output and simple predictors
f <- paste0(dep, " ~ ", pred)

# add squared predictors if some
if(!is.null(sqpred)) {
  f <- paste0(f, " + ", sqpred)
}

# add trend
f <- paste0(f," + trend")

# get formula
f <- as.formula(f)
```

Result

```
output ~ log(inputone) + log(inputtwo) + log(inputthree) + log(inputfour) + 
    I(log(inputone)^2) + I(log(inputtwo)^2) + trend
```

And with your two strange variables as inputone and inputtwo

```
output ~ log(`Trade (% of GDP)`) + log(`[NE.TRD.GNFS.ZS]`) + 
    log(inputthree) + log(inputfour) + I(log(`Trade (% of GDP)`)^2) + 
    I(log(`[NE.TRD.GNFS.ZS]`)^2) + trend
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Billy34. I spent 30 hours trying to solve this. Do you think my mistake was coming from the  fact that I was not adding the condition if(!is.null(sqpred))? Many thanks again, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Yes and also the backquotes. try `paste("log(", NULL,")")` in the console and see what happens

Comment: Silly me! I should have known better :-D. The small example works even without the backquotes. Anyway, many thanks again and take care.

Comment: `reformulate()` can help here to be a bit more clear and compact : `termlabels <- c(sprintf("log(%s)", pred), sprintf("I(log(%s)^2)", sqpred), trend); reformulate(termlabels, dep)`. It would need special casing for `NULL`, but not for `character()`